# vb.net - good ftp control?

Tags: vb.net

I've googled around quite a bit for good vb.net ftp controls and there are a few, but 90% of those are highly priced. Can anyone recommend a good (free or super cheap) control for doing ftp/sftp/ftpssl? Preferably one with a good example application with it as I'm new to vb.net :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason why you really need a control?  Because it would probably be easiest to just use the [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class, which is already in the .NET Framework.  There are [some FTP examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229718.aspx) to help get you started.

Note: this is for FTP only.  SFTP is a completely different protocol that is implemented on top of the SSH stack.  You also mention "ftpssl" which I'm not familiar with -- as far as I know, the FTP standard doesn't include SSL support, so this must be some kind of proprietary extension?  I don't really know how to help you there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The ftpssl I mentioned was more or less auth/implicit protocols which most ftp editors support. I'm just basically creating an ftp editor for my own use and the majority of sites I connect to are my remote linux servers hence the reason I'd like to see SSH as part of the component to simplify my programming :)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/FTP_Client_Control.aspx) could be a good start, it's indeed C#, but you can connect to it from your application, or at least get the idea and write your methods in VB.

http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=+ftp&sbo=kw

Comment: the first example you gave would have been perfect it were in vb.net. I'm a bit too new to try to attempt to convert it into vb though.

Comment: Even you're new, you can look what classes and properties he uses to learn how to use it, for this purposes, vb and c# are almost the same...